# How to write a csv to a particular path when it is on a network drive python

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I have a dataframe (df) and I want to save it down to a location on a network drive. I have tried the following code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

savePath = os.path.join('\\networkdrive\folder1\subfolder1', 'file_name.csv')

df.to_csv(savePath, index=False, header=True)
```

I keep getting an error saying [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\networkdrive\folder1\subfolder1\file_name.csv'

Am i missing something? this usually works for me in subfolders within the same directory I am currently working in, but seems not to be working.

Comment: dask may help: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/how-to/connect-to-remote-data.html

Comment: Hi, what is the output of `Path('\\networkdrive\folder1\subfolder1').exists()` (after adding "from pathlib import Path" at the beginning of your file)?